# Blender destroys PSD file on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, juju, blender, photoshop

I will understand if this question is not related to Ubuntu specifically but on AskBlender did't find any answer.

Installed Blender in Ubuntu with command: `sudo apt install blender` everything installed ok and blender is working. But when I attach PSD file from my another PC with Windows Blender destroys PSD file and turn it to 0b PSD text file.

Krita and GIMP opens PSD files fine, and resaving files throug them did't help, Blender still destroys them.

Comment: Seems like a Blender problem. Ubuntu doesn't destroy files by default.

Comment: @user535733 yeap it doesn't destroy them, atleast if you not asking for it)

Comment: [Importing textured psd into blender not showing correct colors in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40196/importing-textured-psd-into-blender-not-showing-correct-colors-in-blender)

Comment: @karel thank you for the info,  but still can't understand why the same PSD file worked in Blender on Windows, now it's compleatly understandable that thi is only Blender problem, your commen will do as an answer I guess

Comment: That's OK, it's not good enough yet. I'll wait and see.

Comment: Blender uses oiio to read psd files, an oiio install should include `iv` - can that read your psd file without altering it? Blender shouldn't alter the file unless you have something setup to write using that filename.

Comment: @sambler Thank you for your response I installed oiio package atleast I think I install it by compiling it, but still same problem in blender it just makes PSD as text file with 0b weight. Also found some info on blender forums where people says that blender don't have psd support atleas on linux version at all.